# Writing better code for Dialogflow Webhooks

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm currently calling a fulfillment webhook with dialogflow in my node backend, performing crud operations on a firestore db. Is there a better, cleaner way to write these?

My code seems very poorly written but it works. I am striving to write cleaner more readable code so I'm looking for someone to give me some pointers on how to write better API calls with webhooks.

```
//DATABASE API CALLS HERE!// 

  case "FAV_COLOR":
    agent.handleRequest(agent => {
      return new Promise(() => {
        async function writeToDb() {
          // Get parameter from Dialogflow with the string to add to the database doc
          const databaseEntry = agent.parameters.color;
          // Get the database collection 'user' and document 'color' and store
          // the document  {entry: "<value of database entry>"} in the 'color' document
          const dialogflowAgentRef = db.collection("user").doc("color");

          try {
            await db.runTransaction(transaction => {
              transaction.set(dialogflowAgentRef, {
                entry: databaseEntry
              });
              return Promise.resolve("Write complete");
            });
            agent.add(
              `Wrote "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.`
            );
          } catch (e) {
            agent.add(
              `Failed to write "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.`
            );
          }
        }
        writeToDb();
      });
    });
    break;

  default:
    console.log("ITS BROKEN");
```

It's currently inside a switch statement because I want to trigger different fulfillments based on actions. Both agent.add statements don't trigger at all.

Also, if someone could throw in some tips about debugging these I would really appreciate it. I've just been deploying the functions, adding a console.log(JSON.stringify()); and then checking in the firebase console functions section for errors. Seems incredibly inefficient.

Thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Jacks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for peer review to improve working code. It is better suited for [codereview.se], which was created specifically for that purpose. This site is for questions involving code that is not working properly.

Comment: Great thanks Ken, I will move the question there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.js`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const  welcome  = require('./welcome')
const  fallback  = require('./fallback')

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
    intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

You can split files like welcome, fallback

=> `welcome.js`

```
const welcome = (agent) => {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
}
module.exports = welcome
```

=> `fallback.js`

```
const fallback = (agent) => {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
}
module.exports  =  fallback
```

You can use same method with thie [Example](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-firestore-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js)

Comment: That's interesting, your tip has certainly simplified things! Thanks for your response. What I've found is that I have to pass in agent within the intentMap like this:  ```intentMap.set("favColor", updateDB(agent))``` in order to get it to work. 

I've split up my files now like index.js, app.js, and a folder with a list of seperate intent files. My issue now is that the db call only seems to be working 10% of the time. This is definitely a separate issue that perhaps I'll make another thread addressing. Appreciate your time :)

Comment: `intentMap.set('NAME', updateDB);` you can direct assign function like this,